# List of groups and their members for SharePoint Online Team Site

Tags: sharepoint-online, administration, groups, site, team-sites

I realize there are near-duplicate questions, but none with answers that apply to my specific question, for SharePoint Online. Specifically: how can I as a site owner determine what groups are associated with the site, and more critically, the membership of each group? Several sources I have found, including on this site, say that one must use either some form of scripting (ASP or JS), or PowerShell from the Windows command line. This strikes me as odd and at least worth clarifying: is there a **GUI** method to get/edit group membership?

To expand, Microsoft's own documentation says to edit groups by using the Share button ... which doesn't exist for my team site, in my current environment. (I'm a site owner, but not a system-wide administrator or AD administrator.) I can add groups via the Site Permissions, but never delete or edit one? Again, this seems like an implausible design choice for Microsoft. Can I link a SharePoint "List" view to a group and work that way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Click on the 'Gear' icon from left corner of the Office 365 suite bar at the top of your page, then click of 'Site Permissions' link. It will open a visual representation of your groups and members inside it.

[image]

[image]

If you want more information then go to the end of the 'Site Permissions' window where you will see a link 'Advanced permissions settings.' which will land you to the following URL

https://[YourTenant].sharepoint.com/sites/[YourSite]/_layouts/15/user.aspx

Here you should see all permissions, groups, direct accesses, group memberships etc.

Oh, yes, you can directly come to this page as well, if you prepare the link like above respective to your tenant and site.

Here you can create/ remove groups/ permissions etc.

[image]

Comment: This is not the case. The Site Permissions lists only the default groups, and only members added via the Share button. I need all the groups. That interface also does not allow adding/removing anyone. The Advanced Permissions likewise do not list members at all, let alone permit me to change the membership.

Comment: @CarlF Have you tried accessing the advanced permission page using the link I gave? You need to modify it according to you tenant and site. What do you see when trying to access it via direct link? Probably you do not have 'Full Control' over the site collection?

Comment: yes, i did do that. You are quite correct, this is a corporate account, and while I'm site owner, I'm not a SharePoint Administrator.